# Uno Platform Project reports: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found

Tags: c#, uno-platform

[image]

I am trying to create and run an Uno Platform app using Visual Studio Community 2019.
It always reports the error:

The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found

even I downloaded and installed pack at

https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

it still reports same error

your comment welcome

Comment: They will never be found, the legacy .NETFramework ends at 4.8.  Why this project is not asking for ".NETCore,Version=v5.0" is not that obvious.  The project only advertises "Mono for WebAssembly", currently in preview, might have something to do with it.

Comment: You probably forgot to install .NET 5 SDK, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you installed all [prerequisites](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-vs.html#prerequisites).
2. Make sure you installed the **Uno Platform Solution Templates** Visual Studio Extension.
3. Create your project using the **Cross-Platform App** template.

Full guide: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-vs.html

Answer (score 0):

Try move your project from C: to D:.

That's what I did and it worked.

I don't know why.

Try move your project to parent directory, or another directory.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31632926)